# How to plot a discontinue line in R

Tags: r, r-plotly

I want to plot a dicontinue line by city that is to say I want to connect only the points where the dates follow each other.

Code :

```
city = c(rep("paris", 4), rep("lyon", 11), rep("marseille", 10), rep("lille", 5), rep("toulouse", 4), rep("bordeaux", 3))

start = c("2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-07-25", "2018-07-26", "2018-07-27", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-07-29", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05")

max = c(rep(36.4, 4), rep(37.2,3), rep(38.4,8), rep(37.4,10), rep(36.7,5), rep(34.9,4), rep(34.8,3))


tab = as.data.frame(city, start, max)
tab$max = as.numeric(tab$max)
tab$start = as.Date(tab$start)

fig <- plot_ly(tab, x = ~start, y = ~max, color = ~city, mode = 'marker')

fig
```

[image]

I put a cross where I don't want it to connect

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`:

### Data:

```
city <- c(rep("paris", 4), rep("lyon", 11), rep("marseille", 10), rep("lille", 5), rep("toulouse", 4), rep("bordeaux", 3))

start <- c("2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-07-25", "2018-07-26", "2018-07-27", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-07-29", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05")

value <- c(rep(36.4, 4), rep(37.2,3), rep(38.4,8), rep(37.4,10), rep(36.7,5), rep(34.9,4), rep(34.8,3))


tab <- data.frame(city, start, value)
```

### Code:

```
df <- tab %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  mutate(start = as.Date(start)) %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(start + 1 == lead(start),1,0)) %>%
  filter(temp == 0)

tab2 <- tab %>% 
  mutate(start = as.Date(start)) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(start > df$start & city == df$city,paste(city,'0'),paste(city,"1")))
```

### Graph:

```
ggplot(tab2,
       aes(x = start, y = value,
           group = group, colour = city)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image: plot]

On a side note, don't use already existing function (such as `max` for your variable)

Comment: This don't work for me. I have always the line which connect the two point. However I have this message : 

_the size of a longer object is not a multiple of the size of a shorter object_